# In Django, pass parameters in href when a href uses the urlpattern not the url tag

Tags: django, url, parameters, href

I am trying to pass a parameter in a urlpattern not the url tag.

In urls.py,

```
   re_path(r'^send/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/$', views.send_email, name='send_email'),
```

In views.py,

```
   error_messages = { ...
        'inactive': _('<a href="/send/">Please get a new email</a>.'),
    }
```

I have to send a parameter in /send/ how can I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) or [reverse-lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy):

```
 error_messages = { ...
        'inactive': _('<a href="{}">Please get a new email</a>.'.format(reverse('send_email', args=[some_uuid]))),  # where some_uuid will have uuid for the url
    }
```